# about visibility in wordpress regarding of roles

Tags: user-access

I have a problem with my Wordpress side: only admin or editor could use it. Other people could see only general pages but clicking on pictures create error:

//path to picture:

http://.mywordpress_side.. /?attachment_id=819

ERROR:

in Safary:

var_in_0_zero

in Chrome

“page not found”

But when I have role as an admin or an editor,  I could click on the same pictures using the same paths and see the pictures and could enlarge them. Also admin and editor  have edit links and could change pictures.

But roles as subscriber or  author  create error as above.

I want that people be subscribers but could not edit the pictures as admin or editor could do. 
At the same time I would like that those categories(subscriber, author) be able to see the pictures and enlarge them but not see error when they try to do so.

I think that I need to change some setting to allow subscribers have the same privileges as admin(to see photos) but deprive subscribers from editing the photos.

How to do achieve this goal?

thanks.

//edited

the structure of the path is the same for admin and subscriber as below(host is different):

http://family.sfr.com/__trashed/img_0969/

What __trashed mean?

The difference: 
for admin I've got a photo 
for subscriber the error  as below on Chrome:

Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Why it works for admin and not for subscriber?

Comment: does the issue occur even when all plugins have been disabled?

Comment: do you have any template files for attachments? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#attachment

Comment: to Ben: Yes, I've disabled plugins about gallery and still have the same issue.

Comment: I have no templates  as such.  All related gallery files kept on upload folder in my server provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several times download the photos locally but still could not see them as subscriber on my website. Also, even so I could see the photos as admin, I could not as admin to comment them.

Eventually, I've deleted the folder with all photos on my server provider and uploaded the new photos. 
After this procedure I could see all photos as a subscriber. Also I  could comment all photos as an admin or as a subscriber.

I think that I could not see the photos because the photos on server were somehow corrupted. 
 The problem was fixed after uploading the new photos to server.